# What to Do When an Interruption Occurs

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlconnection

I am doing lots of queries to my database with NSURLConnection Asynchronously, I have read a few things on the apple documents as shown below.. however I am still a little confused by whats happening with my request if an interrupt happens and was hoping someone could help me out to understand whats happening and why my responsibilities are.

The apple documents list these things as stuff to handle/think about when an interrupt happens.

> What to Do When an Interruption Occurs
>
> Alert-based interruptions result in a temporary loss of control by
>   your app. Your app continues to run in the foreground, but it does not
>   receive touch events from the system. (It does continue to receive
>   notifications and other types of events, such as accelerometer events,
>   though.) In response to this change, your app should do the following
>   in its applicationWillResignActive: method:
>
> Stop timers and other periodic tasks. Stop any running metadata
>   queries. Do not initiate any new tasks. Pause movie playback (except
>   when playing back over AirPlay). Enter into a pause state if your app
>   is a game. Throttle back OpenGL ES frame rates. Suspend any dispatch
>   queues or operation queues executing non-critical code. (You can
>   continue processing network requests and other time-sensitive
>   background tasks while inactive.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last sentence says it all: You can continue processing network requests while inactive.

Comment: right, how do I handle it though, Say if I make a request thats half way though finishing then I get a call or something similar.. dose the app automatically know to finish that request? or do I need to tell it.. Like wise with other requests that might follow this, will they continue to process or do I need to pause further requests until I go back to an active state?

Might sounds abit stupid but I just want to be clear on this, and understand what I am doing :)

Thanks for your reply however.

Comment: The only issue you really have to deal with is possibly to let the app know you need extra background time, if that's the case.  Your callbacks will still get called every time you get data, until you get the call that it's complete, and then it will go into normal background mode.  Check out: http://mobileorchard.com/ios-advanced-programming-understanding-ios-4-multitasking/

Comment: It's interesting, that in his explanation (of the link you sent me) he says network operations are one of the things you cannot do in the bg.. I'm still reading but yea this is getting abit blurry

Comment: I believe that Apple will let you finish them, provided they don't take too long.  He may also be saying that you can't initiate network operations in the background.